# Number Format in LaTeX

Tags: numbering

My question is: If I want, for example, has a number point separator every three digits, and a comma as decimal separator, I can use this successfully:

```
\num[group-separator = {.},output-decimal-marker = {,}]{X}
```

where "X" is a real number. But if I want the same format throughout the document should I use the same long formula each time? Or I can change some parameter of the preamble to affect globally to the whole document, so that when I enter a number, automatically take that format.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you are using `siunitx`: did you see `\sisetup` in the manual?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved by comments